# Find the fixed points of the system, and sketch the trajectories of the system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations, fixed-point-theorems

I am given the following system:

> $$x' = [(x-1)^2 + y^2]y$$
>
> $$y' = -[(x-1)^2 + y^2]x \tag{*}$$

where $x = x(t), y = y(t)$.

I am supposed to

> Find the fixed points of the system, and sketch the trajectories.

---

Definitions in book:

1. Trajectory

> Let $(u(t),v(t))$ be a solution of the autonomous system:
>
> $$x' = f(x,y)$$
>
> $$y' = g(x,y)$$
>
> with solution curve $C$ in $(t,x,y)$-space. The projection of $C$ onto the $(x,y)$-plane is called the **trajectory** of $(u(t),v(t))$.

2. Fixed point

> The trajectory of a constant solution is a point called a **fixed point** (or a singular point or critical point).

---

So, to get the fixed points we set $x' = 0 = y'$.

We have 4 systems of equations and 4 corresponding solution sets:

1. $$(0,0)$$
2. $$(1,0)$$
3. $$0 = (x-1)^2 + y^2$$
4. $$\emptyset$$

So the constant solutions to the system are given by

$$(u(t),v(t)) = (0,0)$$

and

$$(u(t),v(t)) = (1,0)$$

while their corresponding trajectories are the fixed points $(x,y) = (0,0)$ and $(x,y) = (1,0)$

---

As for the other trajectories, there is this fact in the book that says

> the following systems have the same trajectories:
>
> $$x' = M(x,y)f(x,y)$$
>
> $$y' = M(x,y)g(x,y)$$
>
> and
>
> $$x' = f(x,y)$$
>
> $$y' = g(x,y)$$
>
> if $M > 0$ and $M_x, M_y$ are continuous.

So, if we choose $M = [(x-1)^2 + y^2] > 0$ where $2(x-1), 2y$ are continuous, then I guess the system $(*)$ has the same trajectories as

> $$x' = y$$
>
> $$y' = -x$$

If so, then

$$x'' = y' = -x$$

$$\to x(t) = c_2\sin(t) + c_1\cos(t)$$

and

$$y(t) = c_2\cos(t) - c_1\sin(t) + c_3$$

Then we have trajectories by setting $t=0$:

$$x(0) = c_1$$

$$y(0) = c_2 + c_3$$

---

Any mistakes?

Comment: "Should I find this question, well, not weird?" No. "What other trajectories are there to sketch besides the fixed points?" All of them. "Am I supposed to sketch the trajectories of all the solutions?" Yes. "I think it's supposed to say 'sketch the corresponding solution curves' instead." No. "So how do I sketch (u(t),v(t))=(0,0) and (u(t),v(t))=(1,0)?" Huh? "Are those lines?" What? Each is a point, no?

Comment: @Did I edited my question

Comment: I'll vote to reopen but it's unclear how much help you can expect Readers to give you "to sketch the trajectories".

Comment: @hardmath Thanks ^-^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Note that $r'=0$ and $\theta'=-[(x-1)^2+y^2]$. So, all but three orbits are periodic, right?

**Added:** Here $r,\theta$ are polar coordinates, and we are rewriting the differential equations using the formulas
$$
r'=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)'=\frac{xx'+yy'}{r}
$$
and
$$
\theta'=\left(\arctan\frac yx\right)'=\frac{y'x-x'y}{r^2}
$$
(it isn't really $\arctan(y/x)$ that should be there, due to the second and third quadrants, but the final formula still holds). Other than this, $r'=0$ indicates that all trajectories are contained in circles centered at the origin, while $\theta'\le0$ with $\theta'=0$ if and only if $x=1$ and $y=0$. Now you should make a drawing with circles being traversed in the negative direction, taking into account the two fixed points.

Comment: orbit = trajectory. I don't understand why you edited your question, since my answer gives a complete and I'm sorry to say really immediate solution. Again, all orbits are trajectories are periodic, with the exception of 3 of them.

Comment: I edited my question. We don't have $r$ or $\theta$ at this point in our book. What do you mean?

Comment: @BCLC:  Jonas seems to be suggesting that polar coordinates will make the trajectories easy "to follow".

Comment: @BCLC Just came back. Will add sufficient details to my answer.